# how long can take starting a android emulator (sdk)? 2 hours?

Tags: android, android-emulator

It's first time I started this new API 15 virtual machine after updating `sdk`. I waited about 2 hours until now and emulator starts but stays in android logo. I sets `java_home` and `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` and `path`.

- os: win 8.1 -
- cpu: intel core i7
- java: 8
- sdk: 23.0.5
- android studio:  0.8.14
- avd: api 15, arm v7

I know I can use intel atom but I think with arm it must starts until now.

Comment: Did you try with another API version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. I have no idea why emulator stays in android logo but if you run an application (run as android application in `Eclipse`) by that emulator it will run it and when u exit emulator system will take a snapshot and other times when u run emulator it will run perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Android Emulator always too slow you can try Genymotions, it is very light weight as compared to Android Emulator